# TinyMCE inline mode showing raw HTML rather than formatted output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm attempting to use the [inline mode of TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/use-tinymce-inline/) with an MVC 5 page.  I created the HTML content using a TinyMCE editor in the standard mode as follows:

[image: standard TinyMCE in edit mode]

That data is saved back to the database and then retrieved and displayed on a different page.  On that page I've set up an instance of TinyMCE to display that content in the inline view as follows:

```
  <div id="myeditablediv">@Model.LongDescription</div>

  <script src="~/scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#myeditablediv',
      entity_encoding: 'raw',

      inline: true
    });
  </script>
```

I'd expected that to show the formatted HTML in a clickable TinyMCE control with no toolbars, but instead it's just showing the raw HTML:

[image: inline TinyMCE in read mode]

Clicking on the control does switch it into edit mode and the toolbar appears etc:

[image: inline TinyMCE in edit mode]

so it looks like I'm not passing the data to be rendered to the control correctly when setting up the div with `<div id="myeditablediv">@Model.LongDescription</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your code is escaping the HTML when inserting it back into the page.  I don't know ASP.NET but there is likely something you can do to `@Model.LongDescription` to have it place the raw HTML into the page.

A quick google search suggest this might be the answer:

```
@Html.Raw(@Model.LongDescription)
```